# activeadmin carrierwave image hint not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, carrierwave

HI I am using active admin with carrier gem. I am unable to view preview on image upload in hint
my image src is always empty i.e `f.template.image_tag(f.object.image.url)` is empty

I can see image relative url after clicking upload button.

my form looks like this

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do

  permit_params :name, :description , :category_id , :image
  form(:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
    f.inputs "Product" do
      f.input :category_id , :as => :select , :collection => Category.all
      f.input :name
      f.input :description
      f.input :image, :as => :file, :hint => f.template.image_tag(f.object.image.url) 
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

*model*

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

*serializer*

```
class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description , :image
end
```

my uploader looks like this

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

GENERATE HTML

```
<label class="label" for="product_image">Image</label>
<input id="product_image" name="product[image]" type="file">
<p class="inline-hints"><img src=""></p>
```

Comment: Have you checked that in browser does hint wrap the image src of your in `img` tag I guess they are only meant for text

Comment: yes in browser hint wraps the image src tag. I refered to other stackoverflow question to learn how to put a preview in form which i guess worked for some people.

Comment: can you show us your html code as well along with the image tag that get produce also the which storage provider do you have s3 or file please mention them as well

Comment: Hi I have updated html in question and as the image uploader suggest the storage is file. Just to check if image can be displayed I replaced  f.object.image.url with some random image url and it displayed that image

Answer (score 1):

After a few modifications, for me works fine:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Team do

  permit_params :name, :country :image

  index do
    selectable_column
    column :nome
    column :country
    actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Team" do
      f.input :nome
      f.input :country
      f.input :image, :image_preview => true
    end
    f.actions
  end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :nome
      row :country
      row :image do
          image_tag(equipe.image.url)
      end
    end 
  end

end
```

You can see that I use three options:
 - Index: to show the list of items
 - Form: for the form 
 - Show: to show the item details

This way you can customize all pages.